# How to search in a sorted 2d matrix

Tags: python, numpy

i have got list of x y coordinates:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[2,1],[1,3],[1,5],[2,3],[3,5]])
```

that i've sorted with

```
a=np.sort(a,axis=0)
print a
>[[1 3] [1 5] [2 1] [2 3] [3 5]]
```

i'd like to perform a search :

```
a.searchsorted([2,1])
>Value error : object too deep for desired array
```

Any ideas how to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

This gona work may be , if I got what you asking :

```
>>> a = [[1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 5]]
>>> [2, 1] in a
True
```

Comment: `searchsorted` returns the index of the insertion point for its argument

Comment: They are using NumPy arrays not Python list(i.e try with `[1, 5] in a`; where `a` is NumPy array), plus OP clearly wants something better than `O(N)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yea right, can u explain why it gave false for [1,5]